# Issue with TextInput Keystrokes when Rendering Component via Switch statement

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently facing an issue related to dynamic component rendering using a Switch statement. It would be easier to read the code below in order to get a better understanding.

the getCurrentComponent function has a Switch statement which renders the required Step based on the 'Page' state. The issue is related to the TextInput - whereby, after each keystroke, it would stop typing.

The issue does not occur when rendering the component Step1 without the function getCurrentComponent.

```
export default function AddProductModal({isVisible, toggleModal, page, setPage})  {
    
        const [title, setTitle] = useState('') 
    
        const getCurrentComponent = () => {
               switch (page) {
               case 1:
                   return <Step1/>;
               case 2:
                   return <Step2/>;
               }
        ;}
    
    
        const Step1 = () => (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Gilroy-SemiBold', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 30 }}>Title</Text>
                    <TextInput allowFontScaling={false} value={title} onChangeText={(value) => setTitle(value)} style={styles.singleInput} />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
    )
    
    
    
    return (
         <View>
             {getCurrentComponent()}
         </View>


         {/* Rendering as below works. Above does not */}
         {/* {Step1()} */}

    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face the same issue when coding dynamic number of textInput design. Seems like it is related to **React Native functional component lifecycle**.

When you type inside the textInput and trigger state change, your functional component `getCurrentComponent()` inside `AddProductModal()` will re-render. So the simplest fix is to move the defined functional component out of the main export function.

```
const Step1 = ({title, setTitle}) => (
    //Move it outside
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Gilroy-SemiBold', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 30 }}>Title</Text>
        <TextInput allowFontScaling={false} value={title} onChangeText={(value) => setTitle(value)} style={styles.singleInput} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
)

export default function AddProductModal({isVisible, toggleModal, page, setPage})  {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('') 

    const getCurrentComponent = () => {
           //pass the required data & function by prop
           switch (page) {
           case 1:
               return <Step1 title={title} setTitle={setTitle} />;
           case 2:
               return <Step2/>;
           }
    ;}

    return (
         <View>
             {getCurrentComponent()}
         </View>
    )
}
```